# How to save JSON post to database using PHP-Yii

Tags: php, yii

Yii Application url that provide data to **Ios/Android** application after receiving data from url application **POST** Json to that url.

I need to save **POST** Json to My Database in web

POST json

```
{"universityId": 1,
    "Result":[
        {"id": 1,"label":"Name","value":"Hay"},
        {"id": 2,"label":"Name2","value":"Hay2"}
    ]}
```

Comment: save the raw json string, or the individual components of what's encoded into the json? There's a difference...

Answer (score 0):

```
$result =json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);// to get json


$array =(array)$result; //convert Json to array

    $uid=$array['universityId']; 


        foreach($array['0'] as $datas){  


                $model=new FormData; // create new object
            $model->name=$datas['label']; // assign array value to attributes 
            $model->value=$datas['value'];
            $model->university_id=$uid;
            $model->save(); // save model

            }
```